# Reverse Proxy - Bad Gateway

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, reverse-proxy

For some reasons I need to access https://api.postcodeapi.nu/ with http instead of https. I have created a reverse proxy in my Apache:

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>
ServerName api.postcodeapi.nu.local
SSLProxyEngine on
ProxyPass / https://api.postcodeapi.nu/
ProxyPassReverse / https://api.postcodeapi.nu/
</VirtualHost>
```

Added following line in /etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1      api.postcodeapi.nu.local
```

and accessing with curl but get Bad gateway:

```
# curl http://api.postcodeapi.nu.local
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>502 Bad Gateway</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Bad Gateway</h1>
<p>The proxy server received an invalid
response from an upstream server.<br />
</p>
</body></html>
```

Can someone please help me?

Comment: Is there anything in the Apache error logs?

Comment: Since `curl https://api.postcodeapi.nu/` also generates an error response it is not surprising that making that same request via your reverse proxy also results in an error.

Comment: curl https://api.postcodeapi.nu/ doesn't get bad gateway error but gets following: {"message":"Forbidden"} which is perfectly fine

Comment: Apache logs say [Thu May 24 15:03:35 2018] [error] (502)Unknown error 502: proxy: pass request body failed to 52.85.101.59:443 (api.postcodeapi.nu)
[Thu May 24 15:03:35 2018] [error] proxy: pass request body failed to 52.85.101.59:443 (api.postcodeapi.nu) from 127.0.0.1 ()

Comment: Any help please?

Comment: I tried my original proxy pass configuration in CentOS 7 running Apache/2.4.6 and it works without a problem.

However I have to run it with CentOS 6 as it is not possible to upgrade the O/S at the moment.